# What's the name of this operator?

Tags: abstract-algebra, set-theory, category-theory, model-theory

Let $f,g$ be functions in $C^A$ and $C^B$ respectively.

Let $\boxtimes:C^A \times C^B \to (C\times C)^{A \times B}$ s.t.

$f\boxtimes g(a,b)=(f(a),g(b))$

It seems not the tensor product, nor Cartesian product. Then can we call it direct product? But it seems the term 'direct product' often used on operator between structures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the viewpoint of **category theory**, your map is just $f\times g$ -- it is the image of $f$ and $g$ under the product bifunctor $(-)\times(-)$.

More verbosely, if you compose $f$ and $g$ with the projection maps from $A\times B$, then you get maps $f\circ \pi_1: A\times B \to C$ and $g\circ \pi_2: A\times B \to C$, which factor through $C\times C$ by the universal property of the latter. The mediating morphism is excatly $f\times g$.

If you consider $\mathbf{Set}$ to be a monoidal category by declaring $\times$ to be $\otimes$, then $f\times g$ is indeed the tensor product $f\otimes g$.

---

On the other hand, in ordinary **set theory**, we usually identify a function with its graph: $$f=\{\langle x,f(x)\rangle\mid f(x)\text{ is defined}\},$$ and in that sense your $f\boxtimes g$ is of course not the *cartesian* product of $f$ and $g$. It is closely related though:
$$ f\boxtimes g = \{ \langle\langle a,b\rangle,\langle c,d\rangle\rangle \mid \langle\langle a,c\rangle,\langle b,d\rangle\rangle \in f\times g\}$$
which could be seen as a more vivid justification for Hurkyl's "transpose" terminology.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Your map is some transpose of the Cartesian product.

Given a function $f : A \to B$ and another function $g:C \to D$, their Cartesian product is

$$ f \times g : A \times C \to B \times D : (a,c) \mapsto (f(a), g(c)) $$

The notion of "transpose" enters the picture in the sense that you are switching from thinking about a function $A \to C$ to thinking of an element of $C^A$.

Comment: So does the Cartesian product on functions is a bit different from it on relations though all functions are also binary relations?

Comment: And thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Popopo: Sorry, I forgot about your question. When I talk about the Cartesian product of functions, I think in the categorical sense: the product (bi)functor on the category of sets and functions. I don't know what you have in mind for the Cartesian product of relations, but when I hear the phrase, I also think of the (bi)functor on the category of sets and binary relations. Alas, I don't think in terms of this category often, so I don't know what the product actually is on it to be able to compare them.